# How to avoid losing information when getting 'count' values in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    number       type   username  product publishing_dt          genres 
0             product                 897    2019-03-05             VXA     
1        1     access   kerrigan     1459    2008-05-06         VXA,VHS      
2        1  orderline  45michael    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,B,GT      
3        1  orderline  45michael    86833    2020-02-04          VS,KJM      
4        1  orderline  45michael   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      
5        1  orderline    alicia7   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      
6             product               86217    2017-01-06           B,GTE      
7             product                1459    2020-03-04       GT,VS,KJM      
8        1  orderline      john5   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      
9        1  orderline   kerrigan    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,B,GT      
10       1  orderline   kerrigan  1023897    2020-01-07          GT,VHS      
11       1  orderline     kylemm   537077    2017-05-07          VXA,GT      
12       5     access     uololo   830166    2019-12-05           VXA,B      
13       3     access     7762hc    84325    2018-04-03  VHS,GT,GTE,VXA
```

Where *type* indicates the type of access the user has made to the product (if it was a purchase ('*orderline*'), if it was a visit ('*access*') or if it is just information ('*product*', item nor visited nor purchased), *product* is the unique identifier of the product in question and *number* represents the number of times a user has accessed the product (if *type == access*).

When making:

`df = df.groupby(['number', 'type','username','product', 'publishing_dt', 'genres']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

to get the number of times an item has been seen or purchased by a user I lose all the information related to the *type=product* items.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why are you reassigning the aggregated df to df?

Comment: @NomadMonad I'm just renaming it, making the new df called df too

Comment: But then you lose information about the original df. Isn't that what you want to avoid?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I want to keep the original information inside the new df that's why I was renaming it because I thought that I would keep everything

Comment: There's no such thing as renaming in Python. You bind an object to a name. What you are doing here is reassigning a new DataFrame object to the name `df`. Once you do that the old DataFrame object that was bound to `df` is long gone.

Comment: I know, I know. Anyway, if I change the code line to avoid losing the original datagram, the problem I'm having is the same. I want to keep on the new dataframe all the original data but with the added column count.

Comment: So you want to merge the new DataFrame to the original DataFrame. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Or if you just want to assign a column just `df[new_column] = new_df[target_column]`

Comment: @NomadMonad I've been trying to merge both dataframes, but I want the new information to replace the old one, I don't want to have duplicates.